# Как избавиться от ошибок php

Tags: php, отладка, обработка-ошибок

```
    <?php
$bets = [
    ['name' => 'Иван', 'price' => 11500, 'ts' => strtotime('-' . rand(1, 50) .' minute')],
    ['name' => 'Константин', 'price' => 11000, 'ts' => strtotime('-' . rand(1, 18) .' hour')],
    ['name' => 'Евгений', 'price' => 10500, 'ts' => strtotime('-' . rand(25, 50) .' hour')],
    ['name' => 'Семён', 'price' => 10000, 'ts' => strtotime('last week')]
];

$is_auth = (bool) rand(0, 1);

$user_name = 'Константин';
$user_avatar = 'img/user.jpg';
$categories = ['Доски и лыжи', 'Крепления', 'Ботинки', 'Одежда', 'Инструменты', 'Разное'];
$staff = [
  ['Название' => '2014 Rossignol District Snowboard',
   'Категория' => 'Доски и лыжи',
   'Цена' => '109999',
   'URL картинки' => 'img/lot-1.jpg'
    ],
  ['Название' => 'DC Ply Mens 2016/2017 Snowboard',
   'Категория' => 'Доски и лыжи',
   'Цена' => '159999',
   'URL картинки' => 'img/lot-2.jpg'
    ],
  ['Название' => 'Kpeпления Union Contact Pro 2015 года paзмep L/XL',
   'Категория' => 'Крепления',
   'Цена' => '8000',
   'URL картинки' => 'img/lot-3.jpg'
    ], 
  ['Название' => 'Ботинки для сноуборда DC Mutiny Charocal',
   'Категория' => 'Ботинки',
   'Цена' => '10999',
   'URL картинки' => 'img/lot-4.jpg'
    ], 
  ['Название' => 'Куртка для сноуборда DC Mutiny Charocal',
   'Категория' => 'Одежда',
   'Цена' => '7500',
   'URL картинки' => 'img/lot-5.jpg'
    ],
  ['Название' => 'Маска Oakley Canopy',
   'Категория' => 'Доски и лыжи',
   'Цена' => '5400',
   'URL картинки' => 'img/lot-6.jpg'
    ]
];
function cost ($num) {
    $cost = ceil($num);
    if ($cost > 1000) {
        $cost = number_format($cost, 0, ',' , ' ');
    }
    $cost = $cost . ' ₽';
    return($cost);
}

function renderTemplate($path, $parametres) {
    if (file_exists($path)){
        ob_start();
        print(require_once($path));
        $content = ob_get_clean();
    }
    else {
        $content = '';
    }
    return($content);
}
$content = renderTemplate('templates/index.php', [$categories, $staff]);
print(renderTemplate('templates/layout.php', [$content]));
```

?>[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<main class="container">
    <section class="promo">
        <h2 class="promo__title">Нужен стафф для катки?</h2>
        <p class="promo__text">На нашем интернет-аукционе ты найдёшь самое эксклюзивное сноубордическое и горнолыжное снаряжение.</p>
        <ul class="promo__list">
            <li class="promo__item promo__item--boards">
                <a class="promo__link" href="all-lots.html">Доски и лыжи</a>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__item promo__item--attachment">
                <a class="promo__link" href="all-lots.html">Крепления</a>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__item promo__item--boots">
                <a class="promo__link" href="all-lots.html">Ботинки</a>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__item promo__item--clothing">
                <a class="promo__link" href="all-lots.html">Одежда</a>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__item promo__item--tools">
                <a class="promo__link" href="all-lots.html">Инструменты</a>
            </li>
            <li class="promo__item promo__item--other">
                <a class="promo__link" href="all-lots.html">Разное</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section class="lots">
        <div class="lots__header">
            <h2>Открытые лоты</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="lots__list">
            <?php foreach ($staff as $key => $value){
                print('<li class="lots_item lot"><div class="lot__image"><img src="' . $staff[$key]['URL картинки'] . '" width="350" height="260" alt="Сноуборд"></div><div class="lot__info"><span class"lot__category">' . $staff[$key]['Категория'] . '</span><h3 class="lot__title"><a class="text-link" href="lot.html">' . $staff[$key]['Название'] . '</a></h3><div class="lot__state"><div class="lot__rate"><span class="lot__amount">Стартовая цена</span><span class="lot__cost">' . cost($staff[$key]['Цена']) . '</span></div><div class="lot__timer timer"></div></div></li>');
            } 
            ?>
        </ul>
    </section>
</main>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?=$title; ?></title>
    <link href="css/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<header class="main-header">
    <div class="main-header__container container">
        <h1 class="visually-hidden">YetiCave</h1>
        <a class="main-header__logo">
            <img src="img/logo.svg" width="160" height="39" alt="Логотип компании YetiCave">
        </a>
        <form class="main-header__search" method="get" action="https://echo.htmlacademy.ru">
            <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Поиск лота">
            <input class="main-header__search-btn" type="submit" name="find" value="Найти">
        </form>
        <a class="main-header__add-lot button" href="add-lot.html">Добавить лот</a>

        <nav class="user-menu">

        <?php if($is_auth == true): ?>
            <div class="user-menu_image">
                <img src="<?=$user_avatar; ?>" alt="alt"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><?=$user_name; ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <ul>
                <li class="user-menu_item"><a href="#">Регистрация</a></li>
                <li class="user-menu_item"><a href="#">Вход</a></li>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<?=$content; ?>

<footer class="main-footer">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul class="nav__list container">
            <?php foreach ($categories as $key => $value){
            print('<li class="nav__item">' . $categories[$key] . '</li>');    
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main-footer__bottom container">
        <div class="main-footer__copyright">
            <p>© 2018, YetiCave</p>
            <p>Интернет-аукцион сноубордического и горнолыжного снаряжения</p>
        </div>
        <div class="main-footer__social social">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Мы в соцсетях:</span>
            <a class="social__link social__link--facebook" href="#">Facebook
                <svg width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle stroke="#879296" fill="none" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="12.667"/><path fill="#879296" d="M14.26 20.983h-2.816v-6.626H10.04v-2.28h1.404v-1.364c0-1.862.79-2.922 3.04-2.922h1.87v2.28h-1.17c-.876 0-.972.322-.972.916v1.14h2.212l-.245 2.28h-1.92v6.625z"/></svg>
            </a><span class="visually-hidden">
      ,</span>
            <a class="social__link social__link--twitter" href="#">Twitter
                <svg width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle stroke="#879296" fill="none" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="12.687"/><path fill="#879296" d="M18.38 10.572c.525-.336.913-.848 1.092-1.445-.485.305-1.02.52-1.58.635-.458-.525-1.12-.827-1.816-.83-1.388.063-2.473 1.226-2.44 2.615-.002.2.02.4.06.596-2.017-.144-3.87-1.16-5.076-2.78-.22.403-.335.856-.332 1.315-.01.865.403 1.68 1.104 2.188-.397-.016-.782-.13-1.123-.333-.03 1.207.78 2.272 1.95 2.567-.21.06-.43.09-.653.088-.155.015-.313.015-.47 0 .3 1.045 1.238 1.777 2.324 1.815-.864.724-1.956 1.12-3.083 1.122-.198.013-.397.013-.595 0 1.12.767 2.447 1.18 3.805 1.182 4.57 0 7.066-3.992 7.066-7.456v-.34c.49-.375.912-.835 1.24-1.357-.465.218-.963.36-1.473.42z"/></svg>
            </a><span class="visually-hidden">
      ,</span>
            <a class="social__link social__link--instagram" href="#">Instagram
                <svg width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle stroke="#879296" fill="none" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="12.687"/><path fill="#879296" d="M13.5 8.3h2.567c.403.002.803.075 1.18.213.552.213.988.65 1.2 1.2.14.38.213.778.216 1.18v5.136c-.003.403-.076.803-.215 1.18-.213.552-.65.988-1.2 1.2-.378.14-.778.213-1.18.216h-5.135c-.403-.003-.802-.076-1.18-.215-.552-.214-.988-.65-1.2-1.2-.14-.38-.212-.78-.215-1.182V13.46v-2.566c.003-.403.076-.802.214-1.18.213-.552.65-.988 1.2-1.2.38-.14.778-.212 1.18-.215H13.5m0-1.143h-2.616c-.526.01-1.048.108-1.54.292-.853.33-1.527 1-1.856 1.854-.184.493-.283 1.014-.292 1.542v5.232c.01.526.108 1.048.292 1.54.33.853 1.003 1.527 1.855 1.856.493.184 1.015.283 1.54.293H16.117c.527-.01 1.048-.11 1.54-.293.854-.33 1.527-1.003 1.856-1.855.184-.493.283-1.015.293-1.54V13.46v-2.614c-.01-.528-.11-1.05-.293-1.542-.33-.853-1.002-1.525-1.855-1.855-.493-.185-1.014-.283-1.54-.293-.665.01-.89 0-2.617 0zm0 3.093c-2.51.007-4.07 2.73-2.808 4.898 1.26 2.17 4.398 2.16 5.645-.017.285-.495.434-1.058.433-1.63-.006-1.8-1.47-3.256-3.27-3.25zm0 5.378c-1.63-.007-2.64-1.777-1.82-3.185.823-1.41 2.86-1.4 3.67.017.18.316.276.675.278 1.04.006 1.177-.95 2.133-2.128 2.128zm4.118-5.524c0 .58-.626.94-1.127.65-.5-.29-.5-1.012 0-1.3.116-.067.245-.102.378-.102.418-.005.76.333.76.752z"/></svg>
            </a>
            <span class="visually-hidden">,</span>
            <a class="social__link social__link--vkontakte" href="#">Вконтакте
                <svg width="27" height="27" viewBox="0 0 27 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle stroke="#879296" fill="none" cx="13.5" cy="13.5" r="12.666"/><path fill="#879296" d="M13.92 18.07c.142-.016.278-.074.39-.166.077-.107.118-.237.116-.37 0 0 0-1.13.516-1.296.517-.165 1.208 1.09 1.95 1.58.276.213.624.314.973.28h1.95s.973-.057.525-.837c-.38-.62-.865-1.17-1.432-1.626-1.208-1.1-1.043-.916.41-2.816.886-1.16 1.236-1.86 1.13-2.163-.108-.302-.76-.214-.76-.214h-2.164c-.092-.026-.19-.026-.282 0-.083.058-.15.135-.195.225-.224.57-.49 1.125-.8 1.656-.973 1.61-1.344 1.697-1.51 1.59-.37-.234-.272-.975-.272-1.433 0-1.56.243-2.202-.468-2.377-.32-.075-.647-.108-.974-.098-.604-.052-1.213.01-1.793.186-.243.116-.438.38-.32.4.245.018.474.13.642.31.152.303.225.638.214.975 0 0 .127 1.832-.302 2.056-.43.223-.692-.167-1.55-1.618-.29-.506-.547-1.03-.77-1.57-.038-.09-.098-.17-.174-.233-.1-.065-.214-.108-.332-.128H6.485s-.312 0-.42.137c-.106.135 0 .36 0 .36.87 2 2.022 3.868 3.42 5.543.923.996 2.21 1.573 3.567 1.598z"/></svg>
            </a>
        </div>
        <a class="main-footer__add-lot button" href="add-lot.html">Добавить лот</a>
        <div class="main-footer__developed-by">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Разработано:</span>
            <a class="logo-academy" href="https://htmlacademy.ru/intensive/php">HTML Academy
                <svg width="118" height="40" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 117.01 40">
                    <path fill="#879296"
                          d="M280.33,109.39a2.14,2.14,0,0,1-.6.11.59.59,0,0,1-.66-.66v-3.24c0-2.73-1.62-4-4.18-4a11.08,11.08,0,0,0-3.47.6v1.85a8.05,8.05,0,0,1,3.26-.7c1.54,0,2.37.79,2.37,1.92v.32a12,12,0,0,0-2.36-.26c-1.88,0-4,.72-4,3,0,1.87,1.53,2.77,3.17,2.77a5.25,5.25,0,0,0,3.41-1.17,1.81,1.81,0,0,0,1.81,1.06,3.52,3.52,0,0,0,1.28-.23v-1.45Zm-3.28-.85a3.68,3.68,0,0,1-2.62,1.07c-.9,0-1.7-.45-1.7-1.34,0-1.13,1.21-1.49,2.36-1.49a10.56,10.56,0,0,1,2,.23v1.53Zm9,2.64a6.81,6.81,0,0,0,3-.62V108.7a5.44,5.44,0,0,1-2.64.7,3,3,0,1,1,0-6,4.42,4.42,0,0,1,2.51.75v-1.85a5.47,5.47,0,0,0-2.79-.7,4.69,4.69,0,0,0-5,4.84,4.57,4.57,0,0,0,4.88,4.69Zm8.29-5.8c-1.88,0-4,.72-4,3,0,1.87,1.53,2.77,3.17,2.77a5.25,5.25,0,0,0,3.41-1.17,1.81,1.81,0,0,0,1.81,1.05,3.54,3.54,0,0,0,1.28-.23v-1.45a2.13,2.13,0,0,1-.6.11.59.59,0,0,1-.66-.66v-3.24c0-2.73-1.62-4-4.18-4a11.08,11.08,0,0,0-3.47.6v1.85a8.05,8.05,0,0,1,3.26-.7c1.55,0,2.37.79,2.37,1.92v.32a12,12,0,0,0-2.36-.26Zm2.36,3.17a3.68,3.68,0,0,1-2.62,1.07c-.9,0-1.7-.45-1.7-1.34,0-1.13,1.21-1.49,2.36-1.49a10.56,10.56,0,0,1,2,.23v1.53Zm4.11-2.13a4.49,4.49,0,0,0,4.48,4.77,4.21,4.21,0,0,0,3.47-1.68v1.43h1.81V97.75h-2v5.31a4.19,4.19,0,0,0-3.26-1.41,4.49,4.49,0,0,0-4.48,4.77Zm7.73-1.11v2.2a3.15,3.15,0,0,1-2.88,1.9,3,3,0,0,1,0-6,3.16,3.16,0,0,1,2.88,1.88Zm9.12,5.88a7.75,7.75,0,0,0,3.24-.62v-1.73a6.62,6.62,0,0,1-2.86.64c-1.66,0-3.24-.68-3.47-2.3h6.8c.58-2.62-.66-5.52-4.26-5.52a4.53,4.53,0,0,0-4.58,4.77c0,3.18,2.36,4.77,5.13,4.77Zm-.45-7.86a2.13,2.13,0,0,1,2.36,2.34h-5a2.47,2.47,0,0,1,2.66-2.34Zm18.43,2v5.6h2v-5.65a3.32,3.32,0,0,0-3.43-3.64A4.48,4.48,0,0,0,331,103.1a3.09,3.09,0,0,0-2.83-1.45,4.13,4.13,0,0,0-3,1.38v-1.13h-1.79v9h2v-6.11a3.21,3.21,0,0,1,2.39-1.39,1.72,1.72,0,0,1,1.79,1.9v5.6h2v-5.65c0-.21,0-.41,0-.62a3,3,0,0,1,2.24-1.22,1.72,1.72,0,0,1,1.79,1.9Zm13-3.45h-2.11l-2.69,6.82-3.05-6.82h-2.15l4.3,9.12-.19.45c-.53,1.41-1.26,2.11-2.24,2.11a3.13,3.13,0,0,1-.92-.13v1.71a5.12,5.12,0,0,0,1.19.15c1.38,0,2.66-.79,3.64-3.15l4.24-10.27ZM273.33,89.11a3.18,3.18,0,0,1,2.53-1.51A2,2,0,0,1,278,89.77V95.1h2v-5.6a3.52,3.52,0,0,0-3.73-3.69,4.12,4.12,0,0,0-2.92,1.24V81.91h-2V95.1h2v-6Zm10.18,3.24c0,2.11,1.36,3,3.11,3a7.39,7.39,0,0,0,2.43-.4V93.2a4.87,4.87,0,0,1-1.83.36c-1.17,0-1.72-.4-1.72-1.58V87.83h3.28V86.06h-3.28V82.84l-2,.49v2.73h-1.62v1.77h1.62v4.52ZM293.38,89a3.21,3.21,0,0,1,2.39-1.39,1.72,1.72,0,0,1,1.79,1.9v5.6h2V89.45c0-.21,0-.41,0-.62a3,3,0,0,1,2.24-1.22,1.72,1.72,0,0,1,1.79,1.9v5.6h2V89.45a3.32,3.32,0,0,0-3.43-3.64A4.47,4.47,0,0,0,299,87.26a3.09,3.09,0,0,0-2.83-1.45,4.13,4.13,0,0,0-3,1.38V86.06h-1.79v9h2V89Zm15.16-7.09h2V95.1h-2Zm-61.11-1.57L231.64,82v28.95l15.79,9.4,15.79-9.4V82L247.6,80.35l-.17,0Zm13.73,29.43-13.73,8.17-13.73-8.17V97.9L247.37,106l0,1.47L238,101.93v1.43l9.41,5.66,0,1.51-9.41-5.6v1.43l9.41,5.66,9.5-5.69V104.9h0v-4.67l4.23-2.53v12.06Zm0-13.6-3.76,2.21-1.73,1-8.27-4.92v1.43l7.07,4.2-.06,0-.15.09-1,.59-5.83-3.47v1.43l4.61,2.74-1.09.73,0,0-3.48-2v1.43l2.28,1.34-2.33,1.4-13.6-8.08,13.62-8.19h0l13.79,8Zm0-1.44-13.8-8.14h0l-13.65,8.13V83.85l13.73-1.44,13.73,1.44V94.72Z"
                          transform="translate(-231.64 -80.34)"/>
                </svg>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = renderTemplate('templates/index.php', ['categories' => $categories, 'staff' => $staff]);
print(renderTemplate('templates/layout.php', ['content' => $content]));
```

в функции `renderTemplate` сделать так:

```
ob_start();
extract($parametres);
print(require_once($path));
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

---

Другие переменные, по аналогии, нужно передать с ассоциативным массивом для последующей распаковки в шаблон

Comment: Не ожидал от вас такого совета :) вместо исправления ошибок просто их не выводить? =) тогда уж проще было сделать ```error_reporting(E_ERROR);``` или ```error_reporting(0);```

Comment: Эмм...Ты о чëм? Какие ещё "не выводить ошибки"?

Comment: О самой первой ошибке, is_auth undefined, она куда и как исчезнет? или в играх с буфером вывода мы потеряем этот нотис, или он всё так же останется на странице :) Тут глубже кмк проблема, во первых автору нужно узнать про ```isset``` или ```??```, а во вторых почитать про области видимости и затащить внутрь функции все параметры(или объявить их глобальными что не есть карашо) можно вроде еще ```using``` использовать, но я его редко использую, и не уверен что он тут подойдет :)

Comment: Все необходимые переменные надо будет передать как ассоциативный массив и потом всё распаковать... Дописал об этом.